# Web reference switches from subsite to parent site

Tags: development, web-services

I have an application in which I have added a web reference to:

```
http://base/m/mysite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

I have the following code:

```
MyWebRef.Lists someList = new MyWebRef.Lists();
XmlNode result = someList.GetListAndView("MyList", string.Empty);
```

but for it is throwing a "List does not exist..." error, and when I look at `MyWebRef.URL` it comes back as `http://base/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`

The list in question does not exist here so the error makes sense, but I don't understand why the instance of my web reference is pointing to the base site, when the web reference I added was definately for the subsite.

What am I doing wrong here?  Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: did you find the issue?

Comment: Yes, your answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/_vti_bin` is a virtual directory that is used for the web services and accessible across all sites, similarly to other folders like _/layouts etc.

You can explicitly set the Url property to be from subsite, like:

```
someList.Url = "http://base/m/mysite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
```

Make sure you also authenticate your client:

```
someList.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

P.S. someList is a proxy to web service